# When I use Live HTTP Headers for Firefox, why do I get a piece of random gibberish after the word "callback"?

Tags: http, header, callback

When I loaded a web page after submitting something into a javascript-type "form" I looked at the HTTP headers with the Firefox add-on. Everything in the headers make sense except for 16 random characters in the middle that always came after the word "callback". I don't know what they mean or where they come from.

These are all from SEPERATE "form submissions" if you will.

"http://www.locationary.com/access/proxy.jsp?ACTION_TOKEN=proxy_jsp$JspView$SaveAction&callback=callback8FDRUTrnQgGI2iuZ&inPlaceID=1003168722&xxx_c_1_f_987=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yellowpages.com%2Fdallas-tx%2Fmip%2Fdallas-womens-foundation-13224281%3Flid%3D13224281"

"http://www.locationary.com/access/proxy.jsp?ACTION_TOKEN=proxy_jsp$JspView$SaveAction&callback=callbackPAgvDXBbZuLXbAHw&inPlaceID=1014875244&xxx_c_1_f_987=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yellowpages.com%2Fmorrill-me%2Fmip%2Fshear-talent-country-style-14741614%3Flid%3D14741614"

"http://www.locationary.com/access/proxy.jsp?ACTION_TOKEN=proxy_jsp$JspView$SaveAction&callback=callback5GgVkaOind0ySooX&inPlaceID=1015406723&xxx_c_1_f_987=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yellowpages.com%2Fgalesburg-mi%2Fmip%2Fmichigan-grower-products-8776287%3Flid%3D8776287"

As you can see, they all start out with the same thing:

"http://www.locationary.com/access/proxy.jsp?ACTION_TOKEN=proxy_jsp$JspView$SaveAction&callback=callback"

But after that, there is always a set of 16 seemingly random characters. I understand the rest of this "url" but these 16 characters don't make sense to me. Is there any way to generate them or get them before the request is sent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are almost certainly "AJAX" requests, being used as [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).  The `callback...` value is the name of a dynamically-created JavaScript function to handle the results of the data returned by the HTTP request.

I'd recommend using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to view all of this - it may help shed a little more light on things.

Comment: Is there any way I can get these characters beforehand? What I need to do is create this url myself and then I need to open this url (to submit the "form")

Comment: I have Firebug already but it has a LOT of stuff and I'm confused. I mostly work in Python, not Javascript or AJAX. I'm not sure where to find these 16 characters.

Comment: Given that they're likely randomly generated by the JavaScript framework being used by the page, likely not.  But you probably don't need the the particular names, if you're not interfacing with the rest of the page.  You can just remove the callback argument entirely, and at least with the site's current implementation, normal JSON is returned.  Otherwise, you could provide your own callback name, if you still want to handle the response as JSONP.

Comment: Oh! Okay! So I can just take out the whole callback thing and it will still work? Cool!

Comment: Give it a try.  (It currently works for me.)  However, unless you know something I don't, be warned that this is all very implementation-specific, and that the site could change their formats and such at any time without notice - breaking whatever implementation you come up with.